# Techniques to masquerade a web scraper as a real client?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing a small experimental application that requires data to be scraped from a number of websites.

Currently I have added a random delay (2-20 sec) between subsequent requests and using multiple user agent strings. **What else can be done to help a web scraper evade detection?**

For example, would there be any advantage in setting referrer or x-forwarded-for headers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use [tor](https://www.torproject.org/) and change its frequency to update the IP address more often?

Comment: I had thought about distributing it across a number of ip's but I'm not sure its worth the effort and I may still see some ip's getting banned. 

I had thought that large sites, would see lots of requests from single ip's where NAT is in use. This was the behaviour I was really thinking about simulating.